# Is there a C library that converts integers to hexadecimal or binary?

Tags: c, binary, hex

Is there a library function that takes in an integer and converts it to a single-byte hexadecimal or binary number?

For example, if I passed it the input of `64`, it would output `0x40`.

Comment: You could do it with sprintf - take a look at formatting with %x

Comment: do you need it as a number? if you want it as text you can you `sprintf(str, "0x%X", n)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For hex numbers, you can use `sprintf`:

```
char buff[80];
sprintf(buff, "0x%02x", 64);
```

Comment: Does buff have to be an array? Can't it not be represented in one byte. For example, char a = 0x45.

Comment: I suppose what I was really looking for was how to change an int to a char, which is easier than expected.

Answer (score 2):

An int is an int, whether it is 0x40 or 64; the data representation of the two is exactly the same (10000000...011111111). If you are asking how it would be represented in a char array, you'd use `sprintf`. The simplest way is `sprintf(buf, "%#x", 64)`.

Answer (score 1):

Internally, integers are already represented as binary. You can *display* a number as hexadecimal using the `%x` format string (`%#02x` will fit your example best).

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111928/is-there-a-printf-converter-to-print-in-binary-format) regarding binary, for which there isn't a built-in format string specifier.

Answer (score 1):

In C the [int type's size depends upon implementation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_%28computer_science%29#cnote_b_grp_notesc). Normally, it will be 4 bytes long, and thus impossible to storing in a single byte without losing important information.

If you use a `char` or `int8_t` then you will have a single byte. Bytes are binary internally and always will be. So anytime you want to do *anything* with your byte, you must do it in binary.

Hexadecimal vs binary vs base 10 is a *display decision*. So if you accept those as input, you will have to convert a string into a single byte for storage in memory. When you display them, you will have to convert to the desired display format.

Using [sprintf](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf) works for display. Use [strtol](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtol) for input.

Comment: `short` is never single-byte, assuming byte==octet, and `int` is not "normally" 2 bytes but 4. (The standard requires it to be at least 16 bits, but nobody has used 16-bit ints for 15+ years.)

Comment: @R.. argh! Mixed up pascal shortint with c short. I need to read more carefully. Updated answer.